# Extract a number which is assigned to a string using a Perl script

Tags: scripts, perl

I have a file `input.txt` which has some strings and each string has some values assigned to it.

My task is to write a Perl script to extract the number which is assigned to any of the strings.

For example, given this `input.txt`

```
Tom=0×1234,Bob=0x4567,rock=0x8912.
```

I have to extract the value which is assigned to `rock`.

I need some help writing a script to do this.

Comment: Yes it's possible. But we're not a script writing service.

Comment: Nor a homework service.

Comment: @karel scripting questions are on topic here and always have been! Please don't vote to close on topic posts.

Comment: @thomasrutter scripting questions are on topic here and always have been! Please don't vote to close on topic posts.

Answer (score 6):

One variant on @terdon -- for each /rock=(...)/, say it:

```
perl -nE 'say for /rock=(\w+)/'
```

and a solution with grep

```
grep -Po 'rock=\K\w+' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -lne  '/rock=([^.,]+)/ && print $1' file
0x8912
```

The `/rock=([^.]+)/` will match the string `rock=` and then capture the longest stretch of one or more non-`.` characters (`[^.]+`). The parentheses "capture" the match, and make it available as `$1`. If this matches, `$1` is printed.

The `-l` removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds a newline to each `print` call. The `-n` tells `perl` to read an input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.

Comment: @PerlDuck no, I was giving a specific solution. I edited so that it works with commas as well as full stops though, thanks.

Comment: @PerlDuck picky is fine! I tend to go for the most general solution I can think of, but since the OP here seems to be asking us to do their homework, I didn't feel like making it too easy. And never apologize for corrections, or certainly not to me anyway :)

Answer (score -3):

Something like this

```
echo Tom=0×1234,Bob=0x4567,rock=0x8912 | perl -E'while(<<>>){print map$_->[1],grep$_->[0]=~/rock/,[split/=/]for split/,/,$_}';
```

That compiles with `warnings` and uses the new `<<>>` so it's really good perl code.

Comment: This will also print values associated with `foorock`, `rockfoo`, `forrockbar` etc. It will also print everything together if there's more tha one instance of `rock`. If you really want to use this needlessly convoluted and hard to read approach, you should at least go for `perl -E'while(<<>>){print map$_->[1],grep$_->[0] eq "rock",[split/=/]for split/,/,$_,"\n"}';`.